# Comandos em ASP Classico não rodam e retornam como texto em html

Tags: asp, iis

Estou usando windows 10 e estou tendo problemas pra configurar o meu ASP, ao rodar um script em uma página HTM eu recebo o script por escrito.

```
<% dim x x = "teste" Response.Write(x) %>
```

O meu IIS está rodando normal, tanto que consigo abrir as páginas, porém ele não reconhece a tag do ASP, quando eu rodo algum arquivo .ASP ele me retorna o seguinte erro:

An error occurred on the server when processing the URL. Please contact the system administrator.
If you are the system administrator please click here to find out more about this error.

[image: Imagem da ferramenta de gerenciamento]

[image: Recursos de Desenvolvimento]

Comment: Clicou no "find out more about this error." pra ver o que ele informa?

Comment: Dá uma olhada nesta página, acho que tem algo que possa ajudar: https://iisbrasil.wordpress.com/tag/asp-classico/

Comment: Verifique se você habilitou o caminho pai no IIS, se na pasta do seu site ou sistema tiver o arquivo web.config não configurado apague pois ele passa a comandar tudo e não deixa o IIS exibir erros corretamente. Eu fiz um vídeo no meu canal orientando passo a passo a habilitar o Asp Classico no IIS veja se te ajuda ok [ https://youtu.be/FfSj9VT5nms ]

Comment: dê uma olhada neste site acho que pode te ajudar: https://programano.marsiteshost.com.br/configurando-o-servidor-iis-para-trabalhar-com-asp-classico/